# Api-Plaftom : vuetify generator : issues with nested entity

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js, api-platform.com

I've been using API platform and the Vuetify Client Generator who makes an amazing job!

But now I'm stuck with a problem I can't manage to solve.

Let's say I have an entity in Symfony that has a many to one relationship with another. Like : Article with field title who's the link to Label entity that contains en, fr, de, ... fields.

By default, the client generator make a v-select, which is great, but I want to directly edit the value of fr, en, etc. from Label directly in the Article view.

If I try to do so, I've an error:

> [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.

The code :

```
<v-text-field
      v-model="values.title.fr"          
      :label="$t('fr')"
/>
```

But this in the same template

```
<v-text-field
            v-model="item.slug"
            :error-messages="slugErrors"
            :label="$t('slug')"
            @input="$v.item.slug.$touch()"
            @blur="$v.item.slug.$touch()"
            disabled
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `v-model` it's trying to mutate state value whenever you changing input value.

So use a `computed` property as the model and mutate using set function.

**Template :**

```
<v-text-field
      v-model="fr"          
      :label="$t('fr')"
/>
```

**Script :**

```
computed:{
    fr: {
        get(){ return this.values.title.fr; },
        set(value){ /* mutate state using commit() */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the generator has used vuex-map-fields. And for example, in the same template I also have workin perfectly : <v-text-field
            v-model="item.slug"
            :error-messages="slugErrors"
            :label="$t('slug')"
            @input="$v.item.slug.$touch()"
            @blur="$v.item.slug.$touch()"
            disabled
          />

Comment: @GRUXXKi : `values.title.fr` holding a reference to state value and you cant mutate state value directly

Comment: Yes but, the mutations are generated by updateField in the store. Note sure how I can force commit with that... ?

Comment: @GRUXXKi : you can use `commit` method within the set function in order to update state value

Comment: No, I don't have access to the commit as it is automated by updateField.